Order of precedence for show-set rules in Typst
This is a follow-up question from a question posted on GitHub. The goal is to remove the first-line-indent for the bibliography but it seems that the show par: ... rule takes precedence over the show bibliography: ... one, even though it appears later in the document. What's the logic behind this?
There certainly are other ways to achieve the goal in this example. This question is more about trying to understand the order of precedence of show-set rules in Typst.
#show par: set par(first-line-indent: 1.8em)

#lorem(30)

#lorem(30)

#show bibliography: set par(first-line-indent: 0pt)

#bibliography(
  "literature.bib", 
  title: "References", 
  style: "chicago-author-date",
  full: true
)


Bibliography
@article{bruederle2018,
  title = {Nighttime Lights as a Proxy for Human Development at the Local Level},
  author = {Bruederle, Anna and Hodler, Roland},
  date = {2018-09-05},
  journaltitle = {PLOS ONE},
  shortjournal = {PLoS ONE},
  volume = {13},
  number = {9},
  pages = {e0202231},
  doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0202231}
}

@article{easterly2003,
  title = {Tropics, Germs, and Crops: How Endowments Influence Economic Development},
  shorttitle = {Tropics, Germs, and Crops},
  author = {Easterly, William and Levine, Ross},
  date = {2003-01-01},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Monetary Economics},
  shortjournal = {Journal of Monetary Economics},
  volume = {50},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3--39},
  doi = {10.1016/S0304-3932(02)00200-3},
  keywords = {Economic development,Geography,Institutions}
}

